# What is the sum of reciprocals of first $n$ Euclid numbers

Tags: summation

We know about Euclid Number . I want to know the sum of reciprocals of 1st $n$ Euclid Number ?
In that book I have been told to find the value  of following series :

$$ \dfrac{1}{e_1}+\dfrac{1}{e_2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{e_n}  = ? $$

In fact, I can not understand the following calculations:
   $$ \dfrac{1}{e_1}+\dfrac{1}{e_2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{e_n} = 1 - \dfrac{1}{e_n(e_{n}-1)} = 1-\dfrac{1}{e_{n+1}-1}$$

Can you please help me to find how this sum is done? This math is taken from *"Concrete Math" Of Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth, and Oren Patashnik*.

The definition in this book for Euclid numbers is non-standard: $e_1=2$ and $e_{n+1}=e_1\dots e_n +1$.

Comment: The usual Euclid numbers are $p_0p_1\cdots p_n+1$ where the $p_i$ are the first $n+1$ primes. This must be some other Euclid.

Comment: Where about in the book is this statement?

Comment: On page 108 of Concrete Mathematics, it suggests we define the _Euclid numbers_ by the recurrence: $$e_{n}=e_{1}e_{2}\dots e_{n-1} + 1$$ It then goes on to state that there's a constant $E\approx1.264$, such that: $$e_{n}=\left\lfloor E^{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: And $e_1=2$ to complete the definition.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, sorry, I forgot to include that!!

Comment: I'll fix the edit. There was an ambiguity in your original post, where you wrote "en(en-1)" and meant $e_n(e_n-1)$, but it got reformatted as $e_ne_{n-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $e_1=2$ and $e_{n+1}=e_1\dots e_n+1$, then:

$$\frac{1}{e_1}+...+\frac 1 {e_n} = 1-\frac 1 {e_1\dots e_n} = 1-\frac 1 {e_{n+1}-1}$$

This can easily be proved by induction. Just compute:

$$\frac{1}{e_1}+...+\frac 1 {e_n}  + \frac{1}{e_{n+1}} = 1-\frac 1 {e_{n+1}-1} + \frac{1}{e_{n+1}}$$

Just multiply it out and used that $e_{n+2}-1 = e_{n+1}(e_{n+1}-1)$.

You get the middle term of your question by noting that $$e_1\dots e_n = (e_1\dots e_{n-1})e_n = (e_n-1)e_n$$

Comment: The book actually states that: $$\frac{1}{e_{1}}+\frac{1}{e_{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{e_{n}}=1-\frac{1}{e_{n}(e_{n}-1)}=1-\frac{1}{e_{n+1}-1}$$

Comment: Plz see the edited version . I do not want the proof .

Comment: What do you want, then? A hint for the proof? The hint is: Induction. @SultanAhmedSagor

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your right hand sides are supposed to be, but $\frac 13 + \frac 17=\frac {10}{21}$ and $\frac 13 + \frac 17+\frac 1{31}=\frac{331}{651}$ which do seem to be of the form you list. They seem to be much farther from $1$.

Added:  the Euler numbers you are using are defined by $e_1=2, e_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} e_i +1$.  They start $2,3,7,43,1807,\ldots $ and are given in [A000058 of OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000058) as Sylvester's sequence.  The proof you are looking for is given under Connection with Egyptian fractions in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence)